# hittestresult stopped returning faceindex

Tags: swift3, scenekit

When updating to swift 3, my hittestresult stopped returning the faceindex and no longer works with SCNNodes presentation property. Has anyone found a fix for this?

UPDATE: I traced it down to hitTestResult is only checking bounding box even when setting the optin key bounding box to false.

```
let hitResultsOne = scene.rootNode.hitTestWithSegment(from: pointA, to: pointB, options: [SCNHitTestOption.rootNode.rawValue: myNode.presentation, SCNHitTestOption.boundingBoxOnly.rawValue: false])
```

it returns faceIndex of 0 because the bounding box is 0 from all directions.

Comment: I filed a bug report on this. I tried everything with no luck.

Comment: Post radar number and I'll dupe it.

Comment: Radar # is 28937509.

Comment: Forgot to hit submit earlier. Oops! [Radar Link](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5021868113264640)

Comment: can you show both the Swift 2.x and Swift 3 versions of your code?

Comment: Not near my mac right now. The only thing that changed was presentationNode to presentation. I will post when I get some time. Thx

Comment: MORE INFO - The hit test returns the faceIndex in the simulator. It also does as I expect on the device. I have two point defining a line on the front and back of a sphere (projectile). It updates in the renderer as it passes through space. It recognizes the object and I get a hitTestResult on that object. I just do not get a hitTestResult.first.faceIndex on device only. This leads me to believe it is a metal bug with the swift 3 update.